# Как приписать несколько значений?

Tags: python

```
'if x % 10 == 0 or x % 10 == 1 or x % 10 == 2:' и т.д.

   'print('YES')'
```

Можно всё это дело как-то сократить?

Comment: `if (x % 10) in (0, 1, 2)` или `if 0 <= x % 10 <= 2`

Comment: Хотя на самом деле просто `if False:`, потому что условие в том виде, в котором вы его записали (через and), всегда ложно (если x является числом), потому что одно и то же число не может быть одновременно равно трём разным числам

Comment: @andreymal ну по сути можно весь этот код просто удалить. Потому что ветка if False никогда не будет выполнена.

Comment: Засиделся я что-то, такая глупая ошибка) Спасибо что указали

Comment: @НикитаУ, отметьте и примите, пожалуйста, ответ, что решает вашу проблему :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно:

```
if x % 10 in [0, 1, 2]:
    print('YES')
```

Answer (score 1):

Диапазоны можно проверять через `in` и `range` (он работает лениво, в отличии от решения с списка/кортежа).

Тут `range(2+1)` будет диапазон от 0 до 2 (включительно)

Пример:

```
x = 12
if x % 10 in range(2+1):
    print('YES')
```